# Tab Key on Android Hard Keyboard

Tags: android, android-2.1-eclair

How can I disable a tab key on a form so that it goes to the next button when press.

This is a hardware Tab key on a qwerty hardware keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the `protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {}`, check for the `keyCode` and if the key is tab, then consume the event.

Hope this helps!